# Error trying to use Android admob code for ads with gms 20.2.0

Tags: java, android, admob

I have a file called

Interstitial.java that was already present but i amended to fix the new google ads format and on compile i get error...

```
`Interstitial.java:60: error: class MainActivity is public, should be declared in a file named MainActivity.java`
```

**do i simply move the code to that file or do i need to change the code as well?**

thnks!

Note:I also added a main_activity.xml file - with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SDLActivity">
</LinearLayout>`
```

```
package org.libsdl.app;




//* ADMOB
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
//import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAdLoadCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
// */

import android.app.Activity;

//* ADMOB
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
// */


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
        });
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                        // an ad is loaded.
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                        Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error
                        Log.d(TAG, loadAdError.toString());
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                    }
                });
    }


// */
    }
}`
```

no errors are showing the screen in android studio...just when i try to compile

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned is quite clear:

> Interstitial.java:60: error: class MainActivity is public, should be
> declared in a file named MainActivity.java

**Meaning, that you have declared a class called MainActivity, but the file name of where you placed this class is not called MainActivity.**

Therefore, either rename the file where you placed the class MainActivity to be called MainActivity.java or create a new filed with that name and move the class there.

Since I do not know the file names, I can only assume that you placed the MainActivity class in a file named Interstitial.java, which is the problem.

Comment: Thanks - I have renamed back to Interstitial.java - only some code shown below.... - is the show() targeting the Interstitial.this correct?


public class Interstitial extends Activity {
    public InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    public static Activity currentActivity;

        public void show(int status) {
        if (status==1) {
            if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                mInterstitialAd.show(Interstitial.this);
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The ad wasn't ready yet.");
            }
        }

Comment: @user2511756 - If you have another question, please post it as a separate one. If you have code additions to this question, edit your question and paste it in there. Also, if my answer helped you, please mark it as such.